# Ältere Belege für "Das geht ab wie Schmidts Katze" als 1980er Jahre?

Tags: phrase, etymology

In einer Fernsehsendung wurde behauptet, dass der Spruch

> Das geht ab wie Schmidts Katze!

aus dem Mittelalter stammt, wo angeblich der Schmied auf den Amboss schlägt und die Katze erschreckt. Das halte ich schlichtweg für falsch.

Des Weiteren halte ich es einfach für einen Mode-Spruch, der in der Jugendsprache der späten 80er Jahre entstand und keinen tieferen Hintergrund hat.

Kann mir jemand glaubhafte Belege liefern, dass der Spruch doch vorher entstand?

Comment: Was sagt denn Röhrich dazu?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Schmidts Katze* war definitiv schon vor 1980 auf sehr flinken Pfoten unterwegs. Neueren Ursprungs scheint nur die Kombination mit dem Verb *abgehen* zu sein, jedenfalls habe ich dafür keine älteren Belege gefunden.

Hingegen:

- „Eines Tages war sie **weg, wie Schmidts Katze**, das ist die Jugend“. In: [*Ausgeträumt* von Bulla und Schwefe](https://books.google.de/books?id=Q10aAAAAYAAJ&q=%22schmidts%20katze%22&dq=%22schmidts%20katze%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=atBPVZ66BYHvsAHq2oDwCg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAg) aus dem Jahr 1978
- „**weg wie Schmidts Katze**“ beschrieb die Dichterin Sarah Kirsch (in ihrem Tagebuch?) ihren Umzug nach West-Berlin im Jahr 1977 laut [dieser Quelle](http://www.dichterstaette-sarah-kirsch-online.de/leben.htm)
- „**weg wie Schmieds Katze**“ wird als Redewendung erwähnt in der [Zeitschrift für Mundartforschung, Bd. 13-14](https://books.google.de/books?id=-7cMAAAAIAAJ&q=%22schmieds%20katze%22&dq=%22schmieds%20katze%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=rMdPVY-WGcmUsAG43oH4DA&ved=0CFUQ6AEwCA), aus dem Jahr 1937 [bereits in der Antwort von Carsten Schultz aufgeführt]
- „Ich war weg, rein **weg, wie ‚Schmidts Katze‘**“ ist in einem [Protokoll einer Sitzung des Österreichischen Reichsrates vom 18. Dezember 1913](https://books.google.de/books?id=moAzAQAAMAAJ&q=%22schmidts%20katze%22&dq=%22schmidts%20katze%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=b8RPVce5CcOasgH-ioC4CQ&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBw) zu lesen
- „Die is ja, haste nich gesehn, **fort wie Schmidts Katze**“ in: [*Der Erzketzer: ein Roman vom Leiden des Wahrhaftigen* von Ernst von Wolzogen](https://books.google.de/books?ei=1P1HVdjlMceZsgHP1IGgCQ&id=JaIMAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22wie%20Schmidts%20Katze%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22wie%20Schmidts%20Katze%22) aus dem Jahr 1910 [ebenfalls bereits in der Antwort von Carsten Schultz enthalten]

Die Fundstellen zeigen meines Erachtens allesamt – mal mehr, mal weniger deutlich – die Bedeutung eines sehr schnellen oder plötzlichen Verschwindens. Das passt zumindest zu der Deutung mit dem Schmied. Ich fände es auch plausibel, wenn das dann irgendwann in den 80ern oder 90ern auf das Verb *abgehen* und die allgemeine Bedeutung einer rasanten Bewegung übertragen worden wäre, sprich: hier wurde eine existierende Redeart adaptiert. Einen richtigen Beleg dafür habe ich leider nicht, nur eben das Indiz, dass die Variante mit *weg/fort* sich über einen längeren Zeitraum belegen lässt, ohne dass parallel die Variante mit *abgehen* auftauchen würde.

Nebenbei – des Schmieds Katze kommt noch in einer weiteren Redewendung vor: „Von Danken starb des Schmieds Katze“ (oder alternativ auch die des Henkers). Quelle: [Deutsches Sprichwörter-Lexicon von Karl Friedrich Wilhelm Wander](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/Wander/?lemma=dank) (Eintrag Dank 47, auch 11 und 23). Hilft uns hier zumindest noch als Beleg dafür, dass die Schmiede wohl tatsächlich Katzen von sprichwörtlichem Rang beherbergten.

Answer (score 9):

In „Der Erzketzer: ein Roman vom Leiden des Wahrhaftigen“ von Ernst von Wolzogen aus dem Jahr 1910 findet sich [folgender Dialog](https://books.google.de/books?ei=1P1HVdjlMceZsgHP1IGgCQ&id=JaIMAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22wie+Schmidts+Katze%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22wie+Schmidts+Katze%22).

> »I, was war denn das?« empfing sie ihn ganz gemütlich. »Hat's en Krach gegäb’n?
>   Die is ja, haste nich gesehn, fort wie Schmidts Katze.«

Schmidts Katze scheint also tatsächlich schon älter zu sein, auch wenn die Bezeichnung ihres plötzlichen Abgangs als Abgehen wahrscheinlich neuer ist. In der Zeitschrift für Mundartforschung, Band 13-14, 1937, findet man in einem Aufsatz, den ich leider nicht näher benennen kann, die Variante [„weg wie Schmieds Katze“](https://books.google.de/books?ei=AAFIVeikIMe4sQH9lYCADA&id=-7cMAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22wie+schmieds+Katze%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22wie+schmieds+Katze%22) als gängige Redewendung. Der Schmied ist hier also zumindest keine neue Deutung.

Answer (score 0):

Mir ist *Schmidts Katze* erst in den letzten Jahren häufiger begegnet. Der mittelalterliche Schmied ist die einzige Referenz, die eine schnelle Google-Suche liefert, wobei sich hier jeder auf den anderen zu berufen scheint.

Das lässt den Verdacht zu, dass Du recht haben könntest.

NB: In meinem Umkreis war *Nachbars Lumpi* für so etwas zuständig.

Comment: Verwechselst du da nicht was? Nachbars Lumpi ist spitz. Die Katz hingegen geht rasant ab. Zwei Redensarten, zwei komplett unterschiedliche Bedeutungen. Ich glaube nicht, dass in deinem Umkreis Lumpi der Katz' seine Eigenschaften geerbt hat.

Comment: Darüberhinaus weiß ich nicht, inwiefern deine Antwort eine Antwort ist. Du vermutest, dass die Referenz zum Schmied falsch ist, bietest aber nicht mal eine Theorie auf der deine Vermutung basiert. Geschweige denn Belege. Das ist ein Kommentar wert, aber keine Antwort.

Comment: @Em1 Ich vermute, dass die Referenz falsch sein könnte, da ich nur eine Quelle gefunden habe (wo erklärt wird, _jemand_ hätte das so gesagt) und einige andere Stellen sich auf diese eine Quelle bezogen. Dass Du das mit dem Lumpi nicht glaubst, steht Dir natürlich frei.

Answer (score 0):

Die ältesten Belege für "Schmidts Katze", die ich finden konnte, beziehen sich genauer gesagt auf "Bidder und Schmidts Katze": die Katze, deren Stoffwechsel Friedrich Bidder und Carl Schmidt im Jahr 1851 in einem berühmten (1852 als Teil eines Buchs veröffentlichten Versuchs) 18 Tage lang in einer Apparatur beobachteten, während sie nur Luft und Wasser bekam.

In diesen frühen Belegen ist die Katze zwar nicht auf der Flucht, aber man muss kein Katzenliebhaber sein, um sich ungefähr vorzustellen, wie sich Bidder und Schmidts Katze verhielt, als der Versuch beendet und die Apparatur geöffnet wurde. Es wäre also denkbar, dass "[Bidder und] Schmidts Katze" lange genug ein Objekt von drastischen Schilderungen in Vorlesungen und Vorträgen war, um den Weg in den allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch zu finden.

Ein Indiz für diese Erklärung wäre es, wenn sich in dem Buch "Die Verdauungssäfte und der Stoffwechsel. Eine physiologisch-chemische Untersuchung" (Bidder und Schmidt, Dorpat 1852) eine Erwähnung der Flucht der Katze fände.

Answer (score -1):

Je nach ursprünglicher Verbreitung des Phrasems kann es durchaus sein, dass dieser in einigen Gegenden relativ neu ist.

Da *Schmidt* in all seinen Varianten nicht eindeutig ist, ist der Name leider kein bedeutender Anhaltspunkt, zumal nicht ganz klar ist, ob das Phrasem überhaupt auf einen allgemeinen Familiennamen zurückgeht. Die Schriftform kann darüber nicht hinwegtäuschen.

Andererseits wäre eine ziellose Suche nach Varianten ohne einen Anhaltspunkt über die eigentliche Bedeutung sozusagen zwecklos. Daher ist zu konstertieren, dass *abgehen* trotz lautlicher Schwierigkeiten englisch *to get off* bzw. *go off* in nichts nach steht. In der Fachsprache steht *abgegangen* noch im Bezug auf Ortsnamen in Kotrast zu *bestehend*. Dies kann ferner im Vergleich mit *to forget* "vergessen" bzw. *to forego* "aufgeben, fern bleiben" u.ä. gestützt werden. Vgl. *geht weg / ab wie warme Semmel / friscbe Wecken* (Röhrich).

Ferner wird behauptet

- 1. "Die Katz hingegen geht rasant ab" (@Em1).

Sowie man ebenfalls sagt

- 2. *geht ab wie eine Rakete* (@CarstenS.),

sind weitere Metaphern zu erwarten.

> *Es geht so schnell wie's Katzenmachen*, ↗Brezel, ↗Heftelmacher. [*Röhrich*, s.v. *schnell*]

#### Katz

Englisch kennt *cat* bspw. als eine Art Peitsche mit mehreren Enden, wobei die längere Bezeichnung *cat-o'-nine-tails* eventuel vom Tiernamen abgeleitet ist, allerdings erst seit dem siebzehnten Jahrhundert.

Grimm kennt jedenfalls "katzen" (q.v.) *in mehrfacher Bedeutung unterschiedlichen Ursprungs*, darunter in annähernd vergleichbarer Bedeutung nebst *Katschen*, *Kotze*, *Kâter* auch bspw. *kauze* "flachsbündel in zopfform", nordengl. *cotted* "verwirrt, verfitzt", *cot* "wollabfall, schott". Eine etwaige **schmitskatze* o.ä., was vielleicht auf *skat* hindeuten könnte, ist leider nicht verzeichnet (behaupte ich ohne überhaupt nachzusehen).

Da die Deutung für die ominöse Katze des *Schmieds* sich höchstwahrscheinlich nicht im Zoonym erschöpft, das gleichfalls alt aber mit Hinblick auf ägyptischen Kult nicht ursprünglich im germanischen ist, wenngleich die vordergründige Vorstellung spätestens seit Tom und Jerry jedem präsent ist, muss diese Katze und die im englischen Jargon gemeinte Strafe alt sein. So kennt man auch zu Deutsch einen *Katzenkopf* etwa als Schlag auf den Kopf, vgl. *Pferdekuss* mit der entsprechenden Lautverschiebung (in etwa wie *heart* ~ *Herz* bzw. *foot* - *Fuß*). Wiederum wird das *Skat* genannte Kartenspiel häufig in zusammenhang mit vb. *kloppen* angesprochen. Selbst *schmieden* wird trotz mangelnder Entsprechungen als "schnitzen, mit einem scharfen Werkzeug arbeiten" (DWDS/Pfeifer) bzw. "to cut, hew" (en.wiktionary) etymologisiert.

#### Rakete

Ebenso könnte *Rakete* (s.o.) zu niederländisch *raketsen*, älter Französisch *rachasser* "to strike (the ball) back" (en.wiktionary: racket) zählen, während die Sylvesterrakete auf Umwegen über Lombardisch eventuel auch zu urgermanisch zählt, nämlich rekonstruiertes *rukkô "a distaff, *a staff with flax fibres tied loosely to it*, used in spinning thread" (en.wiktionary, emph. mine).

Insofern die Phrasen zu 1. und 2. also augenscheinlich in der Etymologie übereinstimmen, muss das Phrasem mindestens so alt sein, dass eines das andere ersetzen konnte, was heißt, dass die entsprechende Bedeutung noch erkennbar sein musste. Das heißt allerdings noch nicht, dass "flax fibres tied loosely" bzw. "flachsbündel in zopfform" die einstige Bedeutung hergeben. □

Ob *Rocker* dementsprechend *racketeering* betreiben mag unterdessen dahinstehen.

##### Addendum: Kauderwelsch

Ferner kennt Grimm *Kot, Kote* "hütte, kleines schlechtes haus, ein altes bedeutsames wort" und wohl dazugehörig *Köter, Köther, Kötter*:

> nordd., inhaber einer *kote (s. sp. 1883)*, hindersasz, häusler. auch mlat. schon früh *cotarius, coterellus*, s. Ducange.

> 1. der begriff zeigt starke schwankungen, d. h. er hat eine alte und reiche entwickelung, die ein gut stück des nordd. bäuerlichen gemeindelebens in sich schlieszt, aber hier nur anzudeuten ist.

Und unter 1) b)

> wiederum ist aber doch auch von *kothöfen* die rede, schon im 14. jh. *höve und kothöve Haltaus 1125*, bauern- und kötergüter.

Obwohl da von *Hof* die Rede zu sein scheint, lässt sich aus *Katenrauchwurst, Holsteiner Katenschinken* usw. noch ein Zusammenhang zu *Ofen* oder eher *Räucherkammer* erschließen, so auch *cottage cheese* "Hüttenkäse". Lat. *cotta* "gekocht* dürfte sich dazu verhalten wie *tegula* zu *Schmelztiegel* bzw. *Ziegelei* usw.

Ich vermute, dass gerade die Hütten der Schmiede wegen der Arbeit über offenem Feuer besonders häufig abgebrannt sind. Dafür gibt es auf Englisch einerseits ganz transparent *to spread like a wildfire*, andererseits eine passende Redewendung ohne Schmied, die einen gewissen Bedeutungswandel erfahren hat: *to get along like a house on fire*. Oder als Witz:

> *Why is a pig in a parlour like a house on fire? Because it is best put out immediately.* [*citation needed*]

Dies fügt sich interessanter Weise zu dem Umstand, dass *Kodderschnauze* o.ä. nach einer Etymologie verlangen, die angesichts *Kote* (in etwa wie *Vater* zu niederdeutsch *vadder*) und der Homophonie mit *Köter* vielleicht im Begriff der *Haussprache* begründet liegt, zumal man vom Prahlhans sagt: einen *Kotten schieben* (neudeutsch außerdem *Colonel* /kœʁnəl/, was sicherlich als Hinweis auf den oben beschriebenen *Köther* zu verstehen ist, s. dagegen *eine ruhige Kugel, ein Nümmerchen*, wie auch immer).

Weil *ratschen* (s.o. *rocket*, vgl. *sprocket* "Ratsche, Schnarre, Knarre") ebenso für Geschwätz steht, zumal Grimm weiterhin vb. *katzen* auch als "zanken" führt (vgl. *knatsch*, *sich verkrachen*, oder *kätschen* "Wrestling"), ist kaum mit Sicherheit abzuwägen, wie weit diese Entsprechungen zurückführen. Sobald dabei Lautmerei nahegelegt wird und daher mit freier Variation zu rechnen ist, scheint es schier unmöglich, die Suche sinnvoll einzugrenzen.

Tatsächlich treten beide zusammen auf: "wo ligen meine hausknecht? hieher ihr ketschmägd, die gern am rucken ligen. Fischart groszm. 82 (Sch. 611)." (DWB: *Ketschmagd*).

##### Addendum: *Schmiede*

*TODO...* cf. Röhrich s.v. *Katze, Schmarre(n), schmieren.

---

#### Verweise

DWB (Deutsches Wörterbuch). Jakob und Wilhelm Grimm. https://dwds.de/wb/dwb/

DWDS (Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache)

- Pfeifer, Wolfgang. Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen. https://dwds.de/wb/etymwb/

Röhrich, Lutz. Lexikon der sprichwörtlichen Redewendungen, 3. Auflage.